# mysql — return rows which are not updating by others

Tags: mysql, select, locking

I have a service that many people will visit the database in parallel. At each time, each people will request for 50 records which haven't been processed. e.g.,

```
select * from service where update = -1 limit 50;
```

and then update them manually (which means they will be assigned different value).
What I want to do is to return 50 different records to each people for updating. What's the correct way to achieve it?

I've tried the

```
SELECT ... LIMIT 50 FOR UPDATE;
```

but it seems like it will block the whole database.

Comment: `update` is a reserved keyword, so you may need to escape that when using it as a column name.

Comment: @tadman I just name it for example. Not in the real case.

Comment: Well, all we've got is the example

Answer (score 0):

Don't `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`, but instead have a column specifically for claiming. This is `DEFAULT NULL` but you will populate it with some random or unique identifier. A UUID or other disctinct value will work fine.

For example:

```
UPDATE service SET claimed=? WHERE claimed IS NULL LIMIT 50
```

Pay attention to the modified rows count in the response. If it's greater than zero then you claimed something:

```
SELECT * FROM service WHERE claimed=?
```

That will fetch the previously claimed values.

Comment: In my case, the process is 1) fetch 50 records WHERE claimed IS NULL (and block them so that others can't  read/update them) 2)update the claimed column one by one (which means they are set to different values)
Seems like your solution is not suitable for my case?

Comment: It is, but you need an additional column for claiming purposes. Locking records is really bad in practice, it can cause deadlocks and chaos. Using a column with a lock key (pessimistic lock) is usually pretty reliable.